# Initializing Consumable product to an amount on first use

Tags: unity, c#, in-app-purchase

I am using Unity's In App Purchase plugin to implement an in game store. In my game every player has fuel. I'd like to use the plugin in order to keep track of the amount of fuel the player has so that just erasing the cache on the phone or something wouldn't effect the regeneration time of fuel (like it would if I use PlayerPrefs).

Right now i have it setup so the fuel amount is saved in PlayerPrefs and when fuel is used, a timestamp is saved in PlayerPrefs. Then it checks every once in a while if enough time has passed since they used it in order to regenerate it.

Instead of doingoing it this way I want to initialize the fuel amount in Unity's in app purchase plugin so that Googles servers will have the amount and then I can use the same idea for regeneration that I already have but nowe the amount will be more safe.

Is there a way to initialize the amount of a consumable product a player has on their first launch of a game?

Comment: I would suggest figuring out when the fuel should replenish a unit, and creating a timestamp. When my time says 5:00, I regenerate one fuel. You can then use global time to ensure honesty (i.e, you want to access time through the network). My knowledge of networking is very minimal, but I can still ascertain that global time should be a relatively simple variable to access, through experience and accreditation.

Comment: It appears several games currently implement a form of this method, for example Smurfs. I used to be able to cheat by changing the time forward but now it catches me out and pretty much says I'm a naughty boy lol...

Comment: @Timelord64 Yes currently I upgrade based on how much time has passed since the fuel was last used. I just need to know how I will initialize the amount in the in app purchases so that a player starts off with a certain amount.

Comment: It seems to me like this isn't a matter of the actual in-app purchases system, but rather your save system. I don't have in-depth knowledge of the IAP system, but from what I've gleaned of the documentation, when a purchase is made, you get the data of what was bought, and your script handles the rest. Ex. buy ten fuel, you see the product was "ten fuel" and add ten fuel to the counter in your own scripts, not in Unity's IAP.

Comment: @BHustus I just want to know how to give a person a consumable item in Unity's in app purchase service without them having to buy it. Just a way to initialize the value.

Comment: I know, but, like... by looking at the documentation I don't think you need to do anything in the in app purchase service. You just need to go into the script and make it so fuel = 100 on first play. And when a purchase is made, fuel += whatever amount they purchased. It's not something the store manages. It's something you manage.

Comment: When something is labelled as a "consumable" it just indicates to the store that it can be purchased multiple times. The store doesn't handle how much of it you have. Does this answer the question? If it does, I'll make it a formal answer.

Comment: @BHustus Wow I definitely knew that and just didn't put it together. My last game I used Soomla and took care of it myself. I feel goofy for that one lol. Yes you can make this the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue at hand here isn't a matter of the store, but your program and the way you save files.

Unity Services' built-in In-App Purchasing (IAP) is, in some sense, a complex messaging system. When you register a consumable, it just means it's a repeatable purchase such as "100 gold bars", as opposed to, for example, "New level set", which would only be purchased once.

When you purchase "100 gold bars" or, in your case, a "fuel tank" or something to that effect, your IStoreListener-implementing script will receive a message through ProcessPurchase, and the PurchaseEventArgs will contain the Product representing what the user purchased. From here, you interpret that Product and say, "This Product is X amount of fuel. Add X fuel to the fuel manager". From here, it's up to you to serialize and save that data however you see fit.

For reference, [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityIAP.html) is the official Manual section on Unity Services IAP. It's not a perfect reference and needs some work, but it should give some sense on the workings of creating an in-game store. Also consider looking up classes and interfaces in the Scripting section; I find that the [Product documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Purchasing.Product.html) gives a thorough explanation of implementing IStoreListener.